# How to perform an operation on this tuple and convert to another tuple in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a tuple of tuples that look like this `( (Col1, x, x), (Col2, x, x),  (Col3, x, x) )`
I want to convert it into another tuple that looks like this `(Col1, Col2, Col3)`.

How can this be done?

I am using Python 2.7. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you need to "transpose" a list or something like that, think of `zip`. Try this:

```
a = ( ('Col1', 1, 11), ('Col2', 2, 22), ('Col3', 3, 33) )
print zip(*a)[0]
```

Output:

```
('Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3')
```

---

Edit for a bit more of details:

The `*` operator is used in Python to [unpack argument lists](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists). In other words, the above `zip(*a)` actually translates to

```
zip(('Col1', 1, 11), ('Col2', 2, 22), ('Col3', 3, 33))
```

which results in

```
[('Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3'), (1, 2, 3), (11, 22, 33)]
```

which looks like a transpose of the original tuple, if you regard it as a matrix. Grabbing the first element of the zipped output via `[0]` thus gives the desired output.

Comment: Elegant code. Do you mind explaining what does * mean when used in the context of zip? It looks somewhat unusual and reminds me of the dreaded pointers in C language,

Comment: Sure, please see the edit. Fortunately it has nothing to do with pointers at all :-)

Comment: Sure it is elegant, but remember, from the performance perspective, if the tuples are very big, then the other answers should be preferred.

Answer (score 2):

```
tup_tuples = (("Col1", "x", "x"), ("Col2", "x", "x"), ("Col3", "x", "x") )
print tuple(first for first, _, _ in tup_tuples)
# ('Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3')
```

Comment: Could you explain a little bit that code snippet ? It's kind of nice, but I don't understand the `, _, _` part...

Comment: @Depado `_` is nothing but a variable name (`_` is a valid variable name in Python), which people normally use for use and throw type variables.

Comment: @Depado And `for first, _, _ in tup_tuples` with this, we are unpacking the values of each and every tuple in `tup_tuples` in those variables. And we are using only the `first` value

Comment: Haw right ! I get it now. That's smart. Thanks for the explanation. (I didn't see the unpacking part, that's why it looked like black magic to me)

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
tuple(x[0] for x in big_tuple)
```

Example:

```
>>> big_tuple = ((0,1,1), (1,0,0), (2,3,3))
>>> tuple(x[0] for x in big_tuple)
(0, 1, 2)
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
tuples = ( (Col1, x, x), (Col2, x, x), (Col3, x, x) )
filtered = tuple(t[0] for t in tuples)
```